# Ruby: Testing a ruby string for a substring fails (substring is not recognized)

Tags: ruby, string, character

Using Ruby, I am trying to weed out spam messages the manual way, so why exactly does the below test return `false` when it should return `true`? The tested string is the *original* one, so you can literally copy/paste the whole thing into your ruby console to verify this example:

```
irb(main):053:0> "Веautiful women fоr sеx in yоur town АU: https://links.wtf/qLFs".include? "sex"
=> false
```

Hint: If you replace the word "sex" inside the entire string by typing it in yourself, the test will return `true` as expected. So, somehow, the two "sex" strings are not the same, but on what level? How to test that correctly?

*EDIT*:

I have narrowed it all down to this (copy/paste it to test it!):

```
irb(main):073:0> "е" == "e"
=> false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's `charCodeAt` method tells me that the two characters are a different Unicode value. Ruby's `.ord` method tells me the same thing. You could check against those Unicode values more literally in Ruby, but I'd recommend finding a way to normalize the data instead of adding endless conditionals for unusual characters. It looks like that is a `0x0435 1077 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE` е according to a Unicode lookup table I found online.

Alternatively, here's one approach where you could just ban all Cyrillic characters. I used a full range of excluded characters so you could add exclusions as needed.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

CYRILLIC_UNICODE_DECIMALS = *(1024..1273).freeze

for arg in ARGV
  # next unless arg.is_a?(String)

  arg.split('').each do |char|
    p char if CYRILLIC_UNICODE_DECIMALS.include?(char.ord)
  end
end
```

For reference, these are the `.ord` and `.charCodeAt` methods I used against your example. I started with JavaScript because it's a simple test in the browser console.

```rb
2.6.3 :005 > 'е'.ord
 => 1077
2.6.3 :006 > 'e'.ord
 => 101
```

```js
'"е" == "e"'.charCodeAt(1)
1077
'"e" == "e"'.charCodeAt(1)
101
```

Comment: The easiest approach for this issue will be to scan the string/text in question with the ```gem "unicode-scripts"``` at https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-scripts. Normal text should then return an array containing the 2 following elements at most ```["Common", "Latin"]```. If it contains any other elements, such as in ```["Common", "Cyrillic", "Latin"]```, there's a high chance of the string/text being "obfuscated" spam.